# Ruby 'socket' timeout issue

Tags: ruby

I have the following function for connecting to a HTTP host. I want to properly use timeout. Sometimes seems to work but sometimes doesn't and just hangs forever:

```
def http_send(host, packet, port, timeout = 6)
  addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(host, nil)
  sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, addr[0][3])

  Socket.new(Socket.const_get(addr[0][0]), Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0).tap do |socket|
    socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, 1)

    begin
      socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
    rescue IO::WaitWritable
      if IO.select(nil, [socket], nil, timeout)
        begin
          socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
          socket.write(packet)
          return socket.read
        rescue Errno::EISCONN
        rescue
          socket.close
          puts "[!] Unexpected exception!"
        end
      else
        socket.close
        puts "[!] Connection timeout!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea why that happens? Thanks!

Comment: No ruby gurus around?

Comment: First I'm suspecting `IO.select(nil, [socket], nil, timeout)` expression miss it's surrounding `begin..end` exceptions handling block. Second I'd suggest to try to enclose whole code in `Timeout::timeout` block to test if it properly aborts after a period of time. For testing purposes, of course.

Answer (score -1):

It is work for me:

```
    require 'ipscanner'
require 'socket'
require 'thread'

def open_port(host, port)
  sock = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM)
  raw = Socket.sockaddr_in(port, host)
  #sock.setsockopt( :INET, :connect_timeout, 1 )
  puts "#{host}: #{port} open." if sock.connect(raw)

rescue(Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
rescue(Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
end

def main(host, ports)
threads = []

        ports.each do |makethread|
                threads[makethread] = Thread.new do
                open_port(host, makethread)
                end
        end
end


start_port=1
end_port=700
ip_range_1=200
ip_range_2=200

allports=*(start_port..end_port)
pc=IPScanner.scan(ip_base = '10.166.10.', range = ip_range_1..ip_range_2, t = 5)

pc.each do |pc_ip|
main pc_ip, allports
end
```